# Redux FieldArray component won't populate - getting error: b.equals is not a function

Tags: redux, redux-form

I'm still relatively new to working with redux form, as it is still very much black magic as to how it works, especially when it comes to prepopulating fields from data, it seems to just "happen".

Well I'm in the process of adding a `<FieldArray>` to an existing form that gets populated from data from an `epic` Observable's data. The problem is that the data that comes back is causing an error to occur

```
Uncaught TypeError: b.equals is not a function
    at equals (index.js?3bd9:52)
    at ConnectedFieldArray.shouldComponentUpdate (ConnectedFieldArray.js?c38c:87)
    at checkShouldComponentUpdate (react-dom.development.js?61bb:11191)
    at updateClassInstance (react-dom.development.js?61bb:11640)
    at updateClassComponent (react-dom.development.js?61bb:14648)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js?61bb:15598)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js?61bb:19266)
    at workLoop (react-dom.development.js?61bb:19306)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js?61bb:149)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js?61bb:199)
```

The only thing that makes sense to me is that the component that houses the `<Field>` elements are not matching up, in order for redux to populate the fields appropriately.

Here is my component that is fed into the `<FieldArray>` in my redux form:

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import React, { Fragment } from 'react';
import { Field } from 'redux-form/immutable';

const renderField = ({ input, label, type, meta: { touched, error } }) => (
  <div>
    <label>{label}</label>
    <div>
      <input {...input} type={type} placeholder={label} />
      {touched && error && <span>{error}</span>}
    </div>
  </div>
);

const FormMilestones = ({ fields, meta }) => (
  <Fragment>
    {fields.map((milestone, index) => {
      console.log('milestone?', milestone);
      return (
        <div key={index}>
          <button
            type="button"
            title="Remove milestone"
            onClick={() => fields.remove(index)}
          />
          <Field
            name={`${milestone}.name`}
            component={renderField}
            fullWidth
            autoFocus
            label="Milestone name"
          />
          <Field
            name={`${milestone}.startingAt`}
            component={renderField}
            fullWidth
            autoFocus
            label="Start date"
          />
          <Field
            name={`${milestone}.endingAt`}
            component={renderField}
            fullWidth
            autoFocus
            label="Ending At"
          />
          <Field
            name={`${milestone}.description`}
            component={renderField}
            fullWidth
            autoFocus
            label="Description"
          />
        </div>
      );
    })}
    <button type="button" onClick={() => fields.push()}>
      + Add Milestone
    </button>
  </Fragment>
);
FormMilestones.propTypes = {
  fields: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  meta: PropTypes.object,
};
export default FormMilestones;
```

And here is the `<FieldArray>` that's used in my redux form. I didn't bother to copy the entire form, unless it's necessary, since my functionality issue exists within my `<FormMilestones>` component.

```
<FieldArray
   name="milestones"
   component={FormMilestones}
/>
```

Does anything obvious pop out to anyone?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I tried your code here https://codesandbox.io/s/xvzww7rz4 and I can't see any problem; can you update the sandbox so that it reproduces the error you are having?

Comment: The issue I'm having is coming from when I try to populate my `milestones` `FieldArray`. The component gets the values inside of `fields` except it's not populating the `Field` inputs correctly. Is this due to a naming conflict?

Comment: It can be, but hard to say without seeing initial values. Please share how you initialize the form, possibly on a sandbox.